# Uppdating a variable

Tags: c#, variables

I am making a program where i am trying to get a ball follow a parable curve.

I've written some code where a timer is the value of a variable 'a'.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Class1 class1;
    Class2 class2 = new Class2();

    public Form1()
    {
        Class1 =new Class1(15,a);
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public int a = 0;

    private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        a += 1
    }
 }
```

Class1:

```
class Class1     
{
    private   int radie;
    private   int x;

    public Boll(int p, int c)
    {
        this.radie = p;
        this.x = c;
    }

    public void Rita(Graphics g)
    {
        SolidBrush Brush = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        g.FillEllipse(Brush, x, 100, radie, radie);
    }
}
```

Class 2 is not important since the problem is in class1 where i want the variable 'x' to update alongside with the timer. Now the 'x' only gets the value of the timer when i start debugging. I want the Graphics, in this case the ball to Update (or similar) each time the value of 'x' changes

Comment: You've posted *a lot of code* to only be asking about one variable. Simplify to the smallest self-contained repro. Help us help you.

Comment: Your timer tick increments a by 1 but I'm not sure what else you are expecting to happen at this point. You'd have to call something on Class1 if you want it to be updated... In fact I'd go as far as to note that the only thing that updates x in Class 1 is the `Boll` method that is not being shown to be called anywhere that I can see...

Comment: It's not that much code but it's incomplete, obvious syntax errors, no clear question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in class 1 create a method like this

```
public void Update()
{
// Put logic here to update position for your ball on the curve.
}
```

Call update from class 2 when you increment the time.

```
private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Class1.Update();
    a += 1
}
```

Comment: He needs to have an instance of the class to call Update() on.  It should be passed in as part of EventArgs.  But he didn't include the code where he sets up the timer.